# Значение не выбранного checkbox

Tags: html, css, mysql

Есть у меня checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="visited[]" value="1">
```

Нужно, чтобы он был автоматом со значением "1". Но если пользователь снимает галочку, то все равно в БД заноситься со значение "1". 
А нужно, чтобы было пусто или "0" при снятии.

Comment: так с помощью джс просто забирайте это value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно убрать `value` из атрибутов.
Тег будет автоматически отдавать значение `true или false` (что можно считать, как `1 или 0`).
По стандарту у вас уже включен атрибут `checked`, он будет отдавать `true`. При снятии флажка, соответственно будет передавать `false`.